# where kafka store the meta data on zookeeper ? ( which path ? )

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have ambari cluster with 3 zookeeper servers and 3 kafka machines

hadoop version ( HDP - 2.6.4 )

where kafka store the meta data on zookeeper ? ( which path ? )

I not sure but maybe the data store here?

```
 ls -ltr /data/var/hadoop/zookeeper/version-2
total 5859168
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 199306787 Jan 27 00:02 snapshot.4a00023317
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 199274273 Jan 27 00:03 snapshot.4a0002332b
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 199278370 Jan 27 00:05 snapshot.4a00023349
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 193934228 Jan 29 00:01 snapshot.4a0002ade3
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 193934228 Jan 29 00:03 snapshot.4a0002adf6
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 188207547 Jan 31 00:00 snapshot.4a00033393
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop  67108880 Feb 17 15:08 log.4b0001e57a
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 189085214 Feb 17 15:08 snapshot.4b00046dc8
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop  67108880 Feb 19 20:56 log.4b00046dca
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 190336796 Feb 19 20:56 snapshot.4b0005659b
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop  67108880 Feb 22 01:30 log.4b0005659d
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 190348010 Feb 22 01:30 snapshot.4b000643
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which metadata!

By default, Kafka uses a number of paths in zookeeper:

- `/brokers`: This contains alive brokers as well as topics configuration, assignments and current ISRs
- `/controller`: This ZNode is owned by the current controller in the Kafka cluster
- `/admin`: This contains delete topic requests
- `/config`: This contains overriden configs for brokers, quotas
- And the list goes on ...

The Wiki has a page about ZK data structures but it's out of date and missing a lot of entries: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper

Another thing worth noting is that by default Kafka will create all these paths under / but you can make Kafka use a "chroot" with `zookeeper.connect`. For example if you set it to `localhost:2181/some_path`, all paths will be under `/some_path`: `/some_path/brokers`, `/some_path/controller`, etc

Finally Zookeeper keeps all this data into `log` files on disk. The path is specified by the `dataDir` setting in `zookeeper.properties`. By default with Kafka, it's `/tmp/zookeeper`.

Comment: I search for example the brokers dir but not found it as find / -name brokers

Comment: so am I missed something ?

Comment: do you mean we need to search folders as brokers , controller , ?

Comment: I've added details about ZK `log` files on disk. All the paths I've listed are data within these `log` files

Comment: I update my question , do you mean that the logs that you mentions are under data/var/hadoop/zookeeper/version-2

Answer (score 0):

I see your comment, it's too late but may still helpful for someone face this issue.
Very simple notice, find your topic on zookeeper virtual file system instead of on the zookeeper server node.
through`bin/zkCli.sh -server 【zookeeper server:port】`